# Something not right in the voting system

Tags: support, reputation, voting, up-votes

I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/648475/is-this-an-error-or-a-malware?noredirect=1#comment814940_648475).

I pressed submit, and immediately my question was upvoted, faster than the speed of light, if you are a moderator, I don't if you can check it, but the first vote took less than a second, and I don't know if you are able to know the user who upvoted the question, maybe it's a bot, it will take me at least 30 second to read it and decide if I should upvote or not. the second and the third upvote weren't as fast as the first upvote.

I wanted to come here and report it, as far as I know, on meta you have the same reputation as on the main SO site. My main question was upvoted 3 times, increasing my reputation from 376 I believe or something close to my current reputation.

I came here to report the "faster than the speed of light upvoting incident" and I noticed that my Meta reputation didn't increase.

Right now, I have the same reputation on both Meta and Super User, but that wasn't the case like 10 minutes ago, when I asked the question.

Comment: unless the question appears on the site before it gets submitted...

Comment: not to worry no one actually reads the questions anyway, they like the title :-)

Comment: @Psycogeek thanks for teaching me a good trick boss :)

Comment: @Fischer - I could tell in less then 5 seconds your question was clear and properly documented and worthy of a upvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the hard facts:

- Your question was posted at 16:35:45Z
- Your first upvote was received on 16:35:51Z

That's quite fast indeed. I'm pretty sure the person who upvoted you didn't read the question in its entirety. But since moderators cannot see who voted for which post, we'll never know who that person was or what made them vote so fast.

This definitely doesn't look like voting fraud though, so there is no point in investigating any further.

> Right now, I have the same reputation on both Meta and Super User, but that wasn't the case like 10 minutes ago, when I asked the question.

The reputation syncs on an hourly basis.

Comment: was it 5s difference? wow i think it was less than that, but you have the facts, thanks for your answer sir

Comment: @Fischer You can easily find this out yourself as well: Move your mouse pointer over the text *asked 2 hours ago* (or whatever similar text is shown when you view it) on the question page, and you'll see exactly when it was posted in the tooltip. Then go [here](http://superuser.com/users/195130/fischer?tab=reputation&sort=post) in your user profile, expand the events list for *Is this an error or a malware?* and repeat the above for the oldest (last) entry.

Comment: @DanielBeck Got it! i never thought that the system shows the seconds! never done that, great tip! thumbs up :)